# nodejs - Fast way to make api calls for large number of items and store the results in a file

Tags: performance, node.js, asynchronous

I have a file, which is basically a list of large number of items, around 4-5 lakhs. For each item, I need to make an api call, and store the result in a file.

I tried it using code like this:

```
// 'items' is the array in which I have read all the items from 'source' file 
// and this function is being called in the callback of fs.readFile()
items.forEach(function(item, index){

    function callback(response) {
        var str = '';

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            fs.appendFile('result.txt', str + ',' , function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }

    // make 'options' object from 'item'

    http.request(options, callback).end();
})
```

However, it just wrote only 200 items in around 2 hours. 
How can I speed up this process?

Comment: Could you give information on the size of the files (not number of lines but in MB). What kind of hardware are you running it on so we can rule it out?

Comment: @Deif File size is around 15MB. The reading part hardly takes any time. Also, I am running it on i3 processor, 4GB RAM.